# Create a time picker screen similar to the one Alarm app in Android wear

Tags: android, android-widget, wear-os

I am developing a wearable app where I need to create a Time picker  for my app.
The time picker that is used for mobiles wont fit  for wearable. I need to create a picker similar to the one I see in Alarm app in Android watch. Can anyone help me how to implement that type of time picker screen in my app. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

TimePicker uses by default ***clock*** mode, so by setting it manually to ***spinner***, you'll get view that is more suitable for Wear devices.

Do it by setting ***timePickerMode*** to spinner.

```
 <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner"/>
```

[image]

Comment: The TimePicker fundamentally is a "time of day" picker, not an "amount of time" picker. With a "time of day" picker, numbers larger than 24 in the hours position don't make sense. With an "amount of time" picker, they do make sense.