# Time duration picker dialog or component?

Tags: android, android-timepicker, android-wear-2.0

I'm creating a Wear OS app and I'm giving the user the option to set a timer. In addition to voice commands I'd like to give the option to manually set the duration.

I can adapt the time picker dialog to fit the screen but as far as I can tell there's no native wear specific component or dialog to **choose a duration** of time.

**Wear OS 2.0** has a nice way to select duration from the built in timer app but I haven't found anything about what components were used to create it and if they're available.

I'm really just looking for a user friendly way to set a duration. Any help or guidance would be appreciated! I'm pretty new to Android development.

Comment: I'd recommend to you follow the documentation get the idea about the all pickers(ex time/date). Android Documentation > [pickers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers) and also the picker component is working on wear. you should try this there is a sample code and the simple description about the time picker. [Android - Time Picker](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_timepicker_control.htm) and i hope you might help those questions also [Create a time picker screen similar to the one Alarm app in Android wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093725/c

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't a fan of the design of the time picker component in the context of small screens so I ended up just making my own using some NumberPickers.